# nextjs with pages routing tailwind not applied

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css

I've created a new project, so I don't have any relevant code to attach. I'm trying to establish socket.io server. I've seen that socket.io not working with the new app router so I decided to add a pages router. The problem is that the simple file I've added to the pages folder loads the file and the tailwind isn't applied, although The same file in the app router loads it as expected.

I also added the configuration to the tailwind.config.js file:

```html
 content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,jsx,js}",
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/pages/.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
```